# Maya, Set viewport settings for playblast in standalone

Tags: python-2.7, maya

I'm making a script to playblast without the Maya UI.  The script I've put together successfully creates a playblast but has turned on ligts in the viewport, and because there is no UI panels I can't change the settings using cmds.modelEditor.  Is there a way to choose the viewport settings it uses while in standalone.

Below is a trimmed down version of my script

command line script

```
mayapy myscript.py somefile.ma
```

python script

```
import sys
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.standalone as standalone

standalone.initialize(name='python')

path = sys.argv[1]
args = {...}

cmds.file(path, open = True)
cmds.playblast(**args)

standalone.uninitialize()
```